# Setting up new SDL Web 8.5 Environment

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5

I am currently working on setting up a new SDL Web 8.5 environment.  I have my two CM servers set up and running with load balancing.  I am trying to set up two CD servers in a load balanced configuration.  I will be publishing to three load balanced web servers that will be running two separate web sites.

My question is do I need two sets of CD microservices loaded on each CD server?  I was told that I need a set of microservices for each web site that I have.  I ran the quickinstall.ps1 script and set up the first set of microservices.  I then modified the quickinstall.ps1 file and changed my target folder and also incremented all of my port numbers by 10 for the second set of microservices.  Do I need two sets of microservices for two web sites or can you just configure one set of microservices to use two different broker databases one for each web site?

Answer (score 4):

I found the question a bit ambiguous but let me try to give answer to clarify things:

A general thumb of rule will be that you typically need one set of CD micro-services for all the websites having same **Purpose**. whereas even if you have two websites having different **Purpose**, then you would need Two different set of CD micro-services - one each for a Purpose

So for example: If you have two SDL Tridion powered websites, lets say a Corporate Website and another as a micro-site and they need to be setup for Staging and Live Purposes - then you need One set of CD micro-service for corporate website and micro-site (and any other future websites/micro-sites) for Staging purpose and Another set of micro-service for corporate website and micro-site (and any other future website/micro-site)for Live purpose.

I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and short answers to your questions:

> Do I need two sets of CD microservices loaded on each CD server?

It depends on what is meant by CD server here? because in Tridion you've CD environments, which are usually *Staging* and *Live*, each having a set of  cd microservices of it´s own.

You could choose to deploy both (or each) environments on one server or two servers, depending upon your load-balancing/scaling strategy and design.

> Do I need two sets of microservices for two web sites or can you just configure one set of microservices to use two different broker databases one for each web site?

A website uses a particular CD environment, e.g. Staging or Live, so it always uses one environment(i,e one set of microservices)

I would strongly suggest to look into SDL documentation (including: [Scaling CD envoirnment](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-5570B671-C4CD-4CC9-943B-489E5390C13E&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-E28C9BE0-0060-4C81-8DF8-B9BAC9A3383F.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-5570B671-C4CD-4CC9-943B-489E5390C13E)) and have a good infrastructure design (based on requirements) before implementing it.